# ng-disabled not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

html markup initialize DateDisable= true on load of controller its working fine for me on IE but problem is in chrome browser its not working over there.

```
<p class="input-group" ng-disabled="DateDisable">
    <input datepicker-popup="M/d/yyyy" ng-model="Date" datepicker-options="dateOptions"  />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); open();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
   </p>
```

Java Script code to enable and disable the p tag elements.

```
$scope.DateDisable = false;
```

Comment: Are you setting $scope.DataDisabled with a $digest cycle?

Comment: No i am beginner in angularjs This is the code only i am using in my project.

Comment: Is this code happening inside a angular controller?

Comment: Hmmm Jon Samwell its inside controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but basically paragraph (`<p></p>`) doesn't support disabled attribute.

You can workaround it for example like this:

```
p[disabled]{
    opacity: 0.6;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Css pointer events works in IE >= 11. But you say that `<p disabled></p>` works in IE, so it's ok.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4732/).